# Having clipping problems with 3d bar plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I have a code below that will create a 3d bar plot that can be seen below.

[image]

The problem that I'm having is that some of the bars look wrong within the picture. The bars that look wrong are circled in the picture. When changing 'zsort' to max, min, or average it helps a little, but it still looks messed up. Changing the view with ax.view_init doesn't help much either.

```
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.cm as cm

  xAmplitudes = np.random.exponential(10,10000) #your data here
  yAmplitudes = np.random.normal(50,10,10000) #your other data here - must be same array length

  x = np.array(xAmplitudes)   #turn x,y data into numpy arrays
  y = np.array(yAmplitudes)   #useful for regular matplotlib arrays

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30)) #create a canvas, tell matplotlib it's 3d
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

  #make histogram stuff - set bins - I choose 20x20 because I have a lot of data
  hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(25,25))
  xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])

  xpos = xpos.flatten()/1.
  ypos = ypos.flatten()/1.
  zpos = np.zeros_like (xpos)

  dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
  dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
  dz = hist.flatten()

  cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Get desired colormap - you can change this!
  max_height = np.max(dz)   # get range of colorbars so we can normalize
  min_height = np.min(dz)
  # scale each z to [0,1], and get their rgb values
  rgba = [cmap((k-min_height)/max_height) for k in dz] 

  ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=rgba, zsort='max')
  plt.title("")
  plt.xlabel("")
  plt.ylabel("")
  plt.savefig("")
  ax.view_init(30, -40)
  plt.savefig('3dplot.png')
  plt.show()

  print('ax.azim {}'.format(ax.azim))
  print('ax.elev {}'.format(ax.elev))
```

Could this problem be fixed?

Comment: Not really. It's currently an unsolved problem.

Comment: okay, thank you for letting me know.